# Show $F(x,y)=f(1+x^2+y^2)$ has a local minimum at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ Show that $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $F(x,y)=f(1+x^2+y^2)$ has a local minimum at $(0,0)$.

$f$ has positive derivatives in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I'm struggling getting $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$, because f is single variable.

Is it correct that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)=f'(1+x^2+y^2)2x$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)=f'(1+x^2+y^2)2y$ ?

Comment: Your partial derivative calculation is correct

Comment: Thank you very much, so with that in mind, I can get second derivatives and use the determinant of the matrix to check if local minimum?

Comment: So $f'$ is increasing and $f(1+x^2+y^2)\geq f(1)$.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just $$x^2+y^2+1\geq1.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=0,$ which says that we got a minimal value,

which gives that in $(0,0)$  our function has a local minimum.